# How to load classes as methods like in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started using Codeigniter few days ago and I am wondering how does it work?

I mean the whole loading classes, ex:

```
$this->load->model('model_class_file');
```

and then using it as

```
$this->model_class_file->method();
```

How is it called and what else should I know about php?

Answer (score 1):

Simple `$this->load` is a property which holds a `Loader` object, with a method called `model()` to load model files. The model is then saved onto a private property as an array element.

When accessing `$this->whatever_name_you_put`, PHP will **[magically](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)** search for that index in the private property, and make it available.